# How To automatically click a button after completing a captcha with greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey

i am trying to find a way to automatically click the join raid button in the picture after i complete the captcha. Any help on this would be really appreciated as i'm a complete beginner

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdcowATAAAAAEII5OM69je3C_0hcUcswP4sqQjN">
<input type="submit" style="width: 20em; height: 4em;" value="Join this Raid!" name="submit">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you use jquery or other JS framework?

Answer (score 0):

when your captcha return success then implement this code

**HTML**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdcowATAAAAAEII5OM69je3C_0hcUcswP4sqQjN">
<input type="submit" class="submit_btn" style="width: 20em; height: 4em;" value="Join this Raid!" name="submit">
</div>
```

**JS** this line place into success method of recaptcha:

```
document.querySelector(".submit_btn").click();
```

Comment: how do I implement it after success automatically with greasemonkey is my question. I apologize if it's obvious to you but I am a novice at best.